# xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

Whenever I pass a request to the a webservice web method using google chrome with some input, it gives me a following response:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 101 at column 40: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value
>   0

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

```
840092 10777579 VER 1900-12-31T00:00:00 SYS EMV AKT VIR Arnar Mar Jonsson         Arnar's Bud- og Landbrugscervice 25251628 910673 AKT 2009-10-02T16:21:37 J 2003-    09-18T18:59:40 2399-12-31T00:00:00 N DK 6621 Gesten Gyvelvej 11 0 VIR 2011-11-    05T05:46:03 Arnar's Bud- og Landbrugscervice VIR NKA 2010-06-26T19:12:27 Arnars     Bud- & Landbrugsservice VIR NKA 2010-01-18T06:35:48 Arnar's Bud- og     Landbrugscervice VIR NKA 2009-10-23T06:25:55 Arnar's Bud- og Landbrugscervice v/     Arnar Mar Jonsson VIR NKI 2009-10-05T12:41:28 Arnar'S Bud- og Landbrugscervice V     /Arnar Mar Jonsson VIR NKA 2009-10-05T12:41:28 Arnar'S Bud- og Landbrugscervice     V /Arnar Mar Jonsson v/ Arnar Mar Jon VIR NKI 2004-05-04T15:57:52 Arnar Mar     Jonsson VIR NTI 2004-04-30T17:01:15
```

It renders in a proper way in Internet Explorer.
The XML formed in IE IS :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<IdCardSearchResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns="http://experiannordic.com/">
  <IdCardArray>
    <IdCard>
      <IdCardNo>5840092</IdCardNo> 
      <ConnectedIdCardNo>10777579</ConnectedIdCardNo> 
      <NameProtectionFromDate xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <VerificationType>VER</VerificationType> 
      <VerificationDate>1900-12-31T00:00:00</VerificationDate> 
      <VerificationInit>SYS</VerificationInit> 
      <IdCardType>EMV</IdCardType> 
      <IdCardStatus>AKT</IdCardStatus> 
      <DataSource>VIR</DataSource> 
      <PersonData>
        <FirstName>Arnar</FirstName> 
        <LastName>Mar Jonsson</LastName> 
        <DateOfBirth xsi:nil="true" /> 
        <CprStatusDate xsi:nil="true" /> 
      </PersonData>
      <CompanyData>
        <CompanyName>Arnar's Bud- og Landbrugscervice</CompanyName> 
        <CvrNumber>25251628</CvrNumber> 
        <KobNumber>910673</KobNumber> 
        <KobStatus>AKT</KobStatus> 
        <KobAjourDate>2009-10-02T16:21:37</KobAjourDate> 
      </CompanyData>
      <AddressData>
        <CurrentAddress>J</CurrentAddress> 
        <AddressFromDate>2003-09-18T18:59:40</AddressFromDate> 
        <AddressToDate>2399-12-31T00:00:00</AddressToDate> 
        <ForeignAddress>N</ForeignAddress> 
        <CountryCode>DK</CountryCode> 
        <PostalCode>6621</PostalCode> 
        <PostalDistrict>Gesten</PostalDistrict> 
        <Street>Gyvelvej</Street> 
        <Number>11</Number> 
        <NumberTo>0</NumberTo> 
        <SourceType>VIR</SourceType> 
      </AddressData>
      <DateOfBirth xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <CompanyName>Arnar's Bud- og Landbrugscervice</CompanyName> 
      <Source>VIR</Source> 
      <Type>NKA</Type> 
    </NameData>
    <NameData>
      <CompanyName>Arnars Bud- & Landbrugsservice</CompanyName> 
      <Source>VIR</Source> 
      <Type>NKA</Type> 
    </NameData>
    <NameData>
      <CompanyName>Arnar's Bud- og Landbrugscervice</CompanyName> 
      <CompanyName>Arnar'S Bud- og Landbrugscervice V /Arnar Mar      Jonsson</CompanyName> 
      <CompanyName>Arnar'S Bud- og Landbrugscervice V /Arnar Mar Jonsson v/ Arnar Mar Jon</CompanyName>
      <CompanyName>Arnar's Budservice v/ Arnar Mar Jonsson</CompanyName> 
      <NameToDate xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <DateOfBirth xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <CompanyName>Arnar's Budservice</CompanyName> 
      <Source>VIR</Source> 
      <Type>NKA</Type> 
    </NameData>
      <AddressToDate xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <ForeignAddress>N</ForeignAddress> 
      <CountryCode>DK</CountryCode> 
      <PostalCode>6000</PostalCode> 
      <PostalDistrict>Kolding</PostalDistrict> 
      <Street>Tvedvej</Street> 
      <Number>20</Number> 
      <NumberTo>0</NumberTo> 
      <SourceType>VIR</SourceType> 
      </AddressData>
      </AddressArray>
      <IdCardRelationArray>
        <IdCardRelationData>
          <IdCardNumberFrom>5840092</IdCardNumberFrom> 
          <RelationType>EMV2PER</RelationType> 
          <IdCardNumberTo>10777579</IdCardNumberTo> 
          <IdCardRelationDate>2004-08-14T14:18:27</IdCardRelationDate> 
          <IdCardRelationChangeDate xsi:nil="true" /> 
        </IdCardRelationData>
      </IdCardRelationArray>
    </IdCard>
  </IdCardArray>
</IdCardSearchResponse>
```

Why isn't the data being displayed in google chrome from this request??

Comment: From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File paste the XML data.  VS will give you a list of errors.  Make sure you open the view error window in VS.  You have unmatched open/closed tags.

Comment: You can't use an '&' in following line : Arnars Bud- & Landbrugsservice.  See following webpage : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 3):

Different browsers have different parsing engines and variance in how they handle invalid XML.  In this case Chrome is (correctly) being more strict than IE.

To fix this error you need to replace the & in the following line with `&amp;` which is a valid representation of the "&" character in XML.

```
<CompanyName>Arnars Bud- & Landbrugsservice</CompanyName>
```

Should become:

```
<CompanyName>Arnars Bud- &amp; Landbrugsservice</CompanyName>
```

It’s unfortunate, but you can’t always trust that XML output from other systems will be correctly formed so some logic to either detect that or sanitize it is always prudent.